# Restart Row Number Based on Date and Increments of N

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table with the following data that I generated with a date table

```
date     day_num (DAY_NUM % 7)
2019-07-09  0   0
2019-07-10  1   1
2019-07-11  2   2
2019-07-12  3   3
2019-07-13  4   4
2019-07-14  5   5
2019-07-15  6   6
2019-07-16  7   0
```

I basically want to get a week number that restarts at 0 and I need help figuring out the last part

The final output would look like this

```
date     day_num (DAY_NUM % 7) week num
2019-07-09  0   0        1
2019-07-10  1   1        1
2019-07-11  2   2        1
2019-07-12  3   3        1
2019-07-13  4   4        1
2019-07-14  5   5        1
2019-07-15  6   6        1
2019-07-16  7   0        2
```

This is the sql I have so far

```
select 
SUB.*,
DAY_NUM%7
FROM(
SELECT 
  DISTINCT 
  id_date,
  row_number() over(order by id_date) -1 as day_num 
FROM schema.date_tbl
WHERE Id_date BETWEEN "2019-07-09" AND date_add("2019-07-09",146)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on your query:

```
select SUB.*, DAY_NUM%7,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY FLOOR(DAY_NUM / 7)) as weeknum
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id_date,
             row_number() over(order by id_date) -1 as day_num 
      FROM schema.date_tbl
      WHERE Id_date BETWEEN "2019-07-09" AND date_add("2019-07-09", 146)
     ) x
```